# C Copying a linked list with two pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, char, assert

This is for a school project and I need to finish a function to copy a linked list of employees that looks like this

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee * m_Next;
    struct TEmployee * m_Bak;
    char * m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;
```

this is my function for copying

```
TEMPLOYEE * cloneList(TEMPLOYEE * src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE* current = src;
    TEMPLOYEE* newList = NULL;
    TEMPLOYEE* tail = NULL;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(newList==NULL)
        {
            newList = (TEMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
            newList -> m_Name = current -> m_Name;
            newList -> m_Next = NULL;
            newList -> m_Bak = NULL;
            tail = newList;
        }
        else
        {
            tail -> m_Next = (TEMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
            tail = tail -> m_Next;
            tail -> m_Name = current -> m_Name;
            tail -> m_Next = NULL;
            tail -> m_Bak = current -> m_Bak;
        }
        current = current -> m_Next;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

this works fine but it doesn't copy the m_Bak properly so when I try this assert the m_Next and m_Bak should be the same but aren't

```
assert ( b && ! strcmp ( b -> m_Name, "Maria" ) && b -> m_Bak == b -> m_Next );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The line `xxxx -> m_Name = current -> m_Name;` doesn't clone the string in C, you could memcpy() the whole structure for cloning. I personally prefer to ues calloc to automatically 0-ing a new structure.

Comment: Use strdup to copy a string

Comment: As for style: uppercase names aer typically used for pre-processor names or for the name of `struct`s (e.g. `typedef struct TEMPLOYEE {...}tEmployee;`). Names beginning with `m_` are typically used in C++ to indicate a variable is a property of a class.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
tail -> m_Bak = current -> m_Bak;
```

is wrong as it makes the new list point back to the current list.

You rather need:

```
    else
    {
        tail -> m_Next = (TEMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
        tail -> m_Next -> m_Bak = tail;  // New line
        tail = tail -> m_Next;
        tail -> m_Name = current -> m_Name;
        tail -> m_Next = NULL;
        // tail -> m_Bak = current -> m_Bak; Delete this line
    }
```

Notice that your code does **not** copy the names so both lists will point to the same name object. If you want to do a real copy of the names take a look at `strdup`

Also notice:

You don't need to cast the value returned by `malloc`. However, you should check if `malloc` returned NULL

Comment: thank you, I have changed the name to 
`tail -> m_Name = malloc(strlen(current -> m_Name));
            
strcpy(tail -> m_Name, current -> m_Name);`

The m_Bak copying works for every node after the first one but the first one already has m_Bak address in the original list which doesn't get copied since it's in the if, how should I go about copying it?

Comment: @Lada1208 Use `tail -> m_Name = malloc(1 + strlen(current -> m_Name));` as you need room for the string termination

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee * m_Next;
    struct TEmployee * m_Bak;
    char * m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;

void *Malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if ((ptr = malloc(size)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("alloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}

TEMPLOYEE *cloneList(TEMPLOYEE *src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *newList = (TEMPLOYEE *)Malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
    newList->m_Bak = NULL;

    TEMPLOYEE *copy = newList;
    TEMPLOYEE *current = src;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        newList->m_Name = strdup(current->m_Name);  // need free
        newList->m_Next = NULL;

        if (current = current->m_Next)
        {
            newList->m_Next = (TEMPLOYEE *)Malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
            newList->m_Next->m_Bak = newList;
            newList = newList->m_Next;
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Hope I understand your issue correctly...